# HTML 2 Columns in the Same Row, Header and Paragraph centered vertically with Image

Tags: html, css

I have a problem, I am not able to vertically align ALL my text, I tried searching and I didn't find any solution for my problem.

This link shows what my code looks like when I run it, I am trying to get the Header closer to the paragraph. [Visual of how code looks for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyklN.png)

I am creating (2) `col-sm-6` in the same `<div class="row">`. The right column I would like the picture centered vertically inside the column, and in the left column I would like the paragraph and header to be centered vertically.  The reason for the CSS, I am trying to get it where it scales correctly for any browser window size.

Am I on the right track?

Here is my css

```css
.center { 
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  border: 0px solid green; 
}

.center p {
  margin: 5;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms- transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align: justify; font-family: verdana;"><span style="font-size: large;"><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>&trade;</span></p>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-top: 00px;">

<div class="center">
   
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nonumes voluptatum mel ea, cu case ceteros cum. Novum commodo malorum vix ut. Dolores consequuntur in ius, sale electram dissentiunt quo te. Cu duo omnes invidunt, eos eu mucius fabellas. Stet facilis ius te, quando voluptatibus eos in. Ad vix mundi alterum, integre urbanitas intellegam vix in. Eum facete intellegat ei, ut mazim melius usu. Has elit simul primis ne, regione minimum id cum. Sea deleniti dissentiet ea. Illud mollis moderatius ut per, at qui ubique populo. Eum ad cibo legimus, vim ei quidam fastidii.</p>
   
</div>
 </div>
  
<div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-top: 000px;">
  
<div class="center">
   
<p><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/3500/2095" width="450" height="300" /></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things in your code which one should avoid:

1) Inline `CSS`
2) If the value is 0 then you can drop units. As well as, `padding: 000px;` is wrong. It should be `padding: 0;`

Here is the working code I did by using flex. You don't need positions then. Let me know if it is what you are looking for:

https://codepen.io/NehhaSharma/pen/abbVNvb

Comment: Please include all code relevant to your answer **in the answer itself** don't make us go offsite to find important information.

Comment: Thank you, Jon. sure I will edit the answer and include the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

change your code with this:

html:

```
<p style="text-align: justify; font-family: verdana;"><span style="font-size: large;"><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>&trade;</span></p>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="center">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nonumes voluptatum mel ea, cu case ceteros cum. Novum commodo malorum vix ut. Dolores consequuntur in ius, sale electram dissentiunt quo te. Cu duo omnes invidunt, eos eu mucius fabellas. Stet facilis ius te, quando voluptatibus eos in. Ad vix mundi alterum, integre urbanitas intellegam vix in. Eum facete intellegat ei, ut mazim melius usu. Has elit simul primis ne, regione minimum id cum. Sea deleniti dissentiet ea. Illud mollis moderatius ut per, at qui ubique populo. Eum ad cibo legimus, vim ei quidam fastidii.</p>            
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
         <div class="">
          <p><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/3500/2095" width="450" height="300" /></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.center { 
     width: 100%; 
 }

.center p {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: A good answer should explain how it fixed the problem, not just provide a chunk of code. Finding what has changed in a mass of code can be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

> Can u please try this...

```css
.center { 
  position: relative;
  border: 0px solid green; 
}

.center_text{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -ms- transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.center_text span{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="row">

<div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-top: 0px;">

<div class="center_text">
   <p style="text-align: justify; font-family: verdana;"><span style="font-size: large;"><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>&trade;</span></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nonumes voluptatum mel ea, cu case ceteros cum. Novum commodo malorum vix ut. Dolores consequuntur in ius, sale electram dissentiunt quo te. Cu duo omnes invidunt, eos eu mucius fabellas. Stet facilis ius te, quando voluptatibus eos in. Ad vix mundi alterum</p>
   
</div>
 </div>
 
<div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-top: 0px;">
  
<div class="center">
   
<p><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/3500/2095" width="450" height="300" /></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: A good answer should explain how it fixed the problem, not just provide a chunk of code. Finding what has changed in a mass of code can be tricky.